# Regex for matching numbers with optional decimal digits

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract rating from a tweet using regular expression. For example for below tweet, I want to get the user rating(9.75) and maximum rating(10).

```
This is Logan, the Chow who lived. He solemnly swears he's up to lots of good. 9.75/10
```

I used below regex, but the capture groups 1 and 2 has results 75 and 10. I am not sure why the user rating is captured only after decimal group.

```
.*(\d+\.?\d+)\/(\d*\.?\d*)
```

Comment: Well, there is a "greedy" quantifier issue here, remove `.*`. Then, just use `/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/`

Comment: @PratibhaT [As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

If you want both numbers to have optional decimal you should place the match one or ore `+` and the match zero or more `*` on the correct places, where they match the mandatory leading digit and then the optional decimals

```
(\d+\.?\d+)\/(\d*\.?\d*)
```

with

```
(\d+\.?\d*)\/(\d+\.?\d*)
```

This will match at least one digit followed by maybe a dot and then again maybe some more digits.

Live link: https://regex101.com/r/qc5Zwz/1

Comment: Nice pragmatic simplicity

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+)\b
```

- `\b` - expect a word boundary (eg, space, non-letter character)
- `(` - start capturing the 'rating'
- `\d+` - integer part
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - wrap the decimal part, don’t capture it as a group; make it  optional
- `)` - end of 'rating' capturing group
- `\/`- expect a forward slash
- `(\d+)` - capture the 'maximum'
- `\b` - expect a word boundary again

```js
const text = 'This is Logan, the Chow who lived. He solemnly swears he\'s up to lots of good. 9.75/10'
const pattern = /\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(\d+)\b/
console.log(text.match(pattern))
```

https://regex101.com/r/foO1DF/2